Browser Autoscroll the full dataset
I am trying to scroll the datasheet automatically, untill the end. How I can do that using javascript console.

I tried in this way, but it did not worked.
function autoClickShowMore() { 
    var showMoreButton = document.querySelector('#showMoreHistory256, .showMoreReplies.block a');
 
    if (showMoreButton) {
        console.log('Clicking "Show more" button...');
        showMoreButton.click();
 
        setTimeout(autoClickShowMore, 1000); // Adjust the delay as needed
    } else {
        console.log('No "Show more" button found.');
    }
}

autoClickShowMore();


My another similar question is, hope you can also find some clue from that.

Do you see any errors in your Console? I am assuming when there is no more data, the showMoreButton click event would remove the button? Please provide a [mcve].

you are selecting the wrong element; the <a> tag has no click handler, its parent div is what you want, use this selector instead: div.showMoreReplies

Yes, there are a lot errors in console, as  a begineer i really do't undestand that. If you ran that script in console you will see those errors.

All the data for the chart is fetched from https://sbcharts.investing.com/events_charts/us/1046.json

@GTK Thanks, now i can convert that data easily to my desired format. How you find the json link ?

open devtools/inspect (F12) > network tab > reload page. you will see all network traffic, you can then filter by resource type

@GTK, Thanks a lot. Now, I can easily collect data as my required

I’m voting to close this question because the OP found a different way and no longer cares

Try this:
document.querySelector(".showMoreReplies").click()

Or try this instead of click():
ecEvent.moreHistory(1046, this, 0)


You should explain why. Hard to tell what you think the problem is.
